# Stop a background loop in bash

Tags: bash, loops, background-process

I am currently working on a weird project 'Shellcord', which is a discord bot built only in bash and some builtins.

I am already able to get heartbeat interval. So to my question. My loop looks like this:

```sh
(while true
do
  sleep $interval
  echo '{"op":1,"d":null}' > ws0
done)&
```

Now, I am also able to shut down the bot. However, how can I then stop this heartbeat loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is something like:

```
(while true; do
        sleep $interval
        echo '{"op":1,"d":null}'
done)&
trap "kill $!" 0
```

If you have more to do in the exit cleanup, you'll need something more sophisticated.  You may also be able to set up the trap to signal the process group before you start the loop. Something like:

```
pgid=$(ps -o pgid= $$| tr -d ' ')
trap 'kill -- -$pgid' 0
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use `0` instead of `EXIT` ?

Comment: @Philippe No, EXIT would probably be better.

Comment: Thx, I will try that out and report back asap

Comment: @William Well, capturing 'exit' was not the problem. I already tried killing the loop-pid earlier, however, the sleep process inside it will still be alive and one more ping will occure before everything is cleaned up again

Comment: That shouldn't happen.  The sleep will continue running, but the shell will handle the TERM as soon as the sleep exits, and should terminate before it executes the `echo`.  Unless you have a trap established for TERM that is preventing the exit.  But if you send the TERM to the process group, even the sleep will get the signal and should exit promptly.

Comment: Ah yes, that's correct. Well, this answer brought me to a good idea, therefore, accepted